# How to center text in the middle of a circle?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, calayer, uibezierpath

I have made a circle class, but I want to put text in the direct center of it.

Font size should not matter, the text should always appear in the center.

Up until now, I have simply tried arbitrary values until it is close enough to the center. There has to be an easier way.

```
import UIKit


class CircleView: UIView {
let circleLayer: CAShapeLayer  = CAShapeLayer()

init(frame: CGRect, innerColor: CGColor = Colors.colorWithHexString("#858585").CGColor, rimColor: CGColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2.0, y: frame.size.height / 2.0), radius: (frame.size.width - 10)/2, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0), clockwise: true)

    // Setup the CAShapeLayer
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath
    circleLayer.fillColor = innerColor
    circleLayer.strokeColor = rimColor
    circleLayer.lineWidth = 5.0

    // Don't draw the circle at start
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
    layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
}

func animateCircle(duration: NSTimeInterval) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")

    animation.duration = duration

    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1

    // Do a linear animation 
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    // Do the actual animation
    circleLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Comment: I don't see _any_ text being drawn in your code. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a `UILabel` property in your view named `label`; you can set the `center` value to the center of your view in the   `layoutSubviews` method:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    label.sizeToFit()
    label.center = self.convertPoint(self.center, fromView: self.superview)
}
```

Please note that, this is a lot easier with `Auto Layout`, but you won't be able to change any frame or center like above:

```
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: label, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
    toItem: self, 
    attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
    item: label, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 
    toItem: self, 
    attribute:  NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 
    multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
```